# Use RSA with Eclipse Remote Systems Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, rsa, sftp

I'm using the Remote Systems Explorer (RSE) plugin in Eclipse on my Windows 7 machine to edit files through SFTP on a remote Linux server. I have an RSA key pair setup between my machine and the Linux server, and I can SSH using my keys no problem when I'm at a Cygwin command prompt. I'm not able to get the keys working in Eclipse, though.

I added my RSA private key to Eclipse through Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> SSH2. I also have my public key on the remote Linux server under ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, but I still get a login prompt when I connect to the remote Linux server. How can I setup the RSE plugin so it uses my RSA key to connect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and I solved it simply upgrading to RSE 3.2.2.
The login prompt will appear again. Type the right user id but a dummy password (not the unix user one). It will connect anyway (using the generated keys).

Comment: Instead of a dummy password, you can leave it blank too. Also, choosing "save password" will allow you to then connect without the password dialog appearing.