# Is Eclipse SSH Remote System Explorer broken on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, ssh

I have the following setup on Windows 7 Ultimate x64:

- Eclipse Indigo 2.7.2 (Build: M20120208-0800)
- Remote System Explorer 3.3.2 (see screenshot)
- (Oracle/Sun) Java 1.6 Update 31 (x86)

[image]

Despite all my best efforts I am unable to connect to a remote system (a Centos 5.6 server on my local LAN) using a Remote System Explorer SSH connection - I've tried both password authentication and using my SSH private key.

Here is a screenshot of both the Eclipse error dialogue and what is logged in my `/var/log/secure` log file:

[image]

`/var/log/secure`:

```
Apr  1 12:00:21 nagios sshd[6176]: Received disconnect from 172.16.3.88: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

When I connect for the first time I do get prompted to verify the authenticity of the remote host and the RSA key fingerprint. But that's as far as things go.

Performing the same operation with the same credentials on my Fedora Core 16 box (also running the same version of Eclipse and Java) to the same server (and other servers) is successful.

This leads me to believe that RSE SSH support on Windows is either broken or there's some piece of the SSH-on-Windows puzzle I'm missing. Is this the case?

Comment: It definitely works on windows, I'm using it daily

Comment: Perhaps a quick review of your eclipse ssh key setup?  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration.  I'd also try Putty as a sanity check

Comment: @RoyTruelove - Putty works fine, everything else SSH on my windows box is fine except Eclipse RSE. The Eclipse SSH configuration on Windows is identical to that on my Fedora 16 environment.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom - Sadly I never did. Dunno if this helps though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6487767/419  - my own requirement to use Eclipse on Windows has since passed.

Answer (score 1):

It works on Windows 7 64bit - i am using it. Maybe there is a problem with 3.3.2? I have check my version and i am using 3.3.1

You should upgrade your eclipse. Indigo is deprecated.

Comment: Will try this again when I get time. TBH I've shifted all my non-MS dev onto my Fedora box, but thanks for the answer though.